# Should utilities in Spring context be static or injected?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, utility

I'm writing some utlility methods that helps constructing complex object structures for webservice requests.

When using `Spring`: is it better to provide these classes as static utilities or inject/autowire them?

Example:

```
//the service used to build different parts for the webservice request
class RequestService {
    public addCurrency(Req req) {
        //create currency xml object
        req.addCurrency(cur);
    }

    public addPassengers(Req req, List<String> names) {
        for (String name : names) {
            req.getPassengers().add(passenger);
            //create passengers
        }
    }
}
class WebserviceClient {
     void runWithStatic() {
         Req req = new Req();
         RequestService.addCurrency(req, ..);
         RequestService.addPassengers(req, ..);
         send(req);
     } 

     //or
     @Autowired
     private RequestService reqService;

     void runWithInjected() {
         Req req = new Req();
         reqService.addCurrency(req, ..);
         reqService.addPassengers(req, ..);
         send(req);
     } 
}
```

Is there one approach one would prefer from the overal spring design point of view?

Comment: I would prefer to interface and inject - this allows you to change the implementation of the service at some later point. It also allows you to mock during testing. Using `static` methods in that way is evil - it makes any sort of testing an absolute nightmare.

Comment: Always overengineer everything. You can't go wrong with that approach in Java, according to many voices.

Comment: Seriously, why would you want to dependency-inject stuff like `static boolean equal(Object, Object)` or `logerror(String message)` or any number of such small utility methods?

Comment: As you can read above we are not talking about equation/logging methods...

Comment: Shouldn't `RequestService` be `RequestFactory` and have responsibility for constructing the `Req` object too? That what you aren't hardcoding the `Req` constructor either.

Comment: Hm yes it could have a `getRequest()` method that returns a new req object and thus more being a factory. But that does not change the initial question targeting injection or static reference.

Comment: @membersound I think if you encapsulate the behaviour into a `RequestFactory` then it makes absolute sense to inject the factory. Maybe even a `RequestBuilderFactory` - so you have a `newRequestBuilder` method - then you maintain your `Builder` pattern.